# How to change DigiKam icon

Tags: icons, digikam

I installed digikam. It is great program but I do not like the icon :). Can anybody help me how can it be changed or replaced or whatever for the nicer icon?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The digikam icon is specified in a file called /usr/share/applications/kde4/digikam.desktop or /usr/share/app-install/desktop/kde4_digikam.desktop (I don't know which of them is actually used).

Anyways, these files are simple text documents that you can edit in administrative modus. There are two ways of doing that: text editor or GUI. Text editor:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/kde4/digikam.desktop
```

There is a line in this file that starts with "Icon=". You need to replace the path after that file with the path to the icon of your choice.

GUI:

```
gksudo nautilus /usr/share/applications/kde4
```

Locate digikam.desktop, right click, select "Properties", click on the icon and choose a replacement.